# CentOS VM: Determine whether Anaconda has completed

Tags: centos, vmware-vsphere, anaconda

I'm using VSphere to spin up a series of virtual machines with CentOS 6.5 as the OS.

I'd like to be able to tell, in a bash script, once the OS installation has completed.  I've tried using ping, but that returns true while Anaconda is still running.

Is there a way using either bash or the VSphere API to determine whether the OS installation is complete?

Comment: Why don't you just have the kickstart reboot the machine when it's done?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `touch` a marker file in the `%post` script?

See docs at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-postinstallconfig.html